# Unable to refresh JTabbedPane

Tags: swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am using JTabbedPane with JPanel to display JTable on one tab and text, dropdown and jbutton on other tab. 
First time it is working fine but if i minimize or switch screen to other application and come back to my application it display data correct but with a serious problem with tab change in JTabbedPane. Now tab screen goes to blue and don't display the data.(I hope data is there but it is not repainting or refreshing complete window). 
Now with blue screen i do the same procedure and change tab in JTabbedPane it shows correct data.
I used repaint but it doesn't work.
Help needed to refresh window or tab correctly.

Comment: I am displaying browser to show pdf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may problem of Browser you are using jdic.dll. Try using any other browser to reload your tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this "issue" is an evergreen. I assume, that most people stumble over this issue possibly when implementing JTabbedPane changes (removing and adding of tabs) in the wrong event-method:

For example, if you want to remove a tab and add a new one in the tabbed pane based on a selection in a JComboBox, you have to put your logic into an 'itemStateChanged'-event of the ItemListener added to this combo-box. If you put your tab-change-logic e.g. into an propertyChangeEvent (PropertyChangeListener), you are doing it all wrong and the timing is always messed up for repainting/refreshing tabbed pane UI elements!

If you use the right event-method, you don't even have to call setVisible, revalidate nor repaint. It will all work out perfectly.

Here's a simple example:

```
JComboBox<String> c_editor = new javax.swing.JComboBox<String>();

c_editor.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(
            new String[] { "CSV", "EXCEL", "HTML" }
        ));

c_editor.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
            c_editorItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });

...

protected void c_editorItemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {

    // get the value selected in the combo box
    final String val = c_editor.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (tabbed_pane.getTabCount() > 1) {
        // remove the panel which is at position 1
        tabbed_pane.removeTabAt(1);
    }

    if (val.equals("CSV")) {
        // add the panel for viewing CSV files
        tabbed_pane.addTab("CSV Editor", p_csv);
    } else if (val.equals("EXCEL")) {
        // add the panel for viewing Excel files
        tabbed_pane.addTab("Excel Editor", p_excel);
    } else if (val.equals("HTML")) {
        // add the panel for viewing HTML files
        tabbed_pane.addTab("HTML Editor", p_html);
    }
}
```

That's all, nothing else necessary - the UI will update itself. PS: This issue has nothing to do with browsers as suggested by the 'favoured' answer in this thread, it's all about Java Swing GUI's.